# How can I calculate average from data stored in Core Data SwiftUI

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I'm working on an app that keeps track of all my grades in school in SwiftUI.
I'm using a TextField where I can pass in my grades. (In Germany we use numbers from 1 - 15, where 1 is the worst and 15 is the best). I'm storing that data in Core Data.

I have an Entity: Grades,
and an Attribute: points (String)

```
@FetchRequest(entity: Grades.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var grades : FetchedResults<Grades>

List {
ForEach(noten){ note in
CellInfo(noteInfo: note)
}
  }
```

I have a List with a ForEach View to visualize it. This is how it looks like:

[image: This is how it looks like]

My question is: How can I get the average of all my Grades calculated and shown at the bottom?

Comment: If grade is a number then store it as a number (Int).

Comment: But how do I store the value of the textField as an Int and how do I get the Int values to get the average from it?

Comment: How do you store the value today? Basically all you need to do is to use `let value =  Int(someText) ?? 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a computed property to calculate the average value

```
var average: Double {
    Double(grades.map(\.points).reduce(0, +)) / Double(grades.count)
}
```

If points is a String you need to convert it

```
var average: Double {
    grades.map { Double($0.points) ?? 0 }.reduce(0, +)) / Double(grades.count)
}
```

and then display it below your list

```
Text("\(average)")
```